# multiple ssh commands on remote server

Tags: bash, ssh

We have some remote servers with a dynamic RSA key used for logging in.

I'd like to write a script that lets me do a few commands that all take a long time, meaning, the RSA key is changed in between.

Is this even possible?

I currently have

```
scp file user@host:/path . #asks for password
ssh user@host "command2" #asks for password
```

but what I want is something like:

```
# create some ssh connection to server (ask for password)
scp_command1 #(doesn't need password)
# long time goes by
command2 #(doesn't need password)
```

Comment: How do you get the correct key if you are doing this manually? You'll have to automate that process somehow.

Comment: Are you forcibly logged out if the key changes while you are logged in? If not, you could open a single long-lived connection in "master" mode with the `-M` option, and piggyback off that for the other connections.

Comment: @chepner, I'm not logged out. Could you please show what you mean by a master mode connection.

Comment: When `ssh` is run in master mode, another connection to the same host can "piggyback" on the master, skipping the need to reauthenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You can run both command as:

```
command1 && command2
```

in this way command2 starts when command1 completes.

Comment: I think you typoed a `.` in your command. Moreover, `command2` will only start when `command1` completes *with a 0 exit-code*, which may or may not be desired behaviour.